# Value undefined returned from fetch (promise)

Tags: javascript, html, promise

I think i'm not understanding promises correctly. What I understand is that `fetch()` returns a promise, I try to use the `.then()` to return the value in the promise, but i always get undefined. What additionally confuses me is that I can `console.log()` and it shows data, but when I try to use it elsewhere it returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var getData = function(){

    var getRaceData = function()
    {
        fetch('http://ergast.com/api/f1/2008.json')
        .then(function(response) {
            response.json().then(function(data) {
                var raceSeason = data.MRData.RaceTable; 
                var raceData = raceSeason.Races;
                console.log(raceData);
                // Not returning racedata here, always get undefined
                return raceData;
            });
            }
        )
        .catch(function(err) {
            return;
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: `getRaceData` has no return statement so it will always return `undefined`. The functions you pass to `then` and `catch` are *different functions*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the result of calling `response.json().then(...)`. Typically you'd do that by chaining on the first `then`'s result rather than nesting (nesting has its uses, but probably not here). You also need to return the overall chain (assuming the data is supposed to leave `getRaceData`):

```
var getData = function(){

    var getRaceData = function()
    {
        return fetch('http://ergast.com/api/f1/2008.json')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            var raceSeason = data.MRData.RaceTable; 
            var raceData = raceSeason.Races;
            console.log(raceData);
            return raceData;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            return;
        });
    }
}
```

---

A couple of other notes, though:

1. You're not checking for HTTP errors. This is a footgun in the `fetch` API, it only rejects on *network* errors, not HTTP errors. Instead, you have to add a check.
2. Ideally, you'd report or otherwise handle the rejection rather than letting it fail silently. :-)
3. The code in `getData` only *creates* a function, it doesn't call it. But I assume you're calling it in code you haven't shown.

So:

```
var getData = function(){
    var getRaceData = function()
    {
        fetch('http://ergast.com/api/f1/2008.json')
        .then(function(response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            var raceSeason = data.MRData.RaceTable; 
            var raceData = raceSeason.Races;
            console.log(raceData);
            return raceData;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // ...report/handle the error...
        });
    };
    // Presumbly use `getRaceData` here; the code above only *defines* it.
};
```

Comment: `getRaceData` has no `return` statement. Only the `then` callbacks do.

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks, good eye. For some reason I thought it was being used inline, but then the inner `return raceData` wouldn't be neded.